# Simpler method to show $k(x)$ is NOT a primitive irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

Let $k(x) = x^2+2x+2$ be under $\mathbb Z_{11}[x]$. Determine if $k(x)$ is irreducible, and if so, determine if it is primitive.

Ok, I showed that $k(x)$ is irreducible since it it a quadratic and has no linear factors.

A field constructed with $k(x)$ would have order $11^2=121$...and so the multiplicative group would have $120$ elements. If $x$ generates this group under multiplication modulo $k(x)$, then I would know that $k(x)$ is primitive. However, I would have to calculate $x^1,x^2,...,x^{120}$ to show this...

I figured that it would be ridiculous for a question like this to result in $k(x)$ being primitive, but what if it were? Would I really have to calculate $x^1,x^2,...,x^{120}$ in order to demonstrate this? Is there a much more efficient way of solving a problem like this?

Comment: A polynomial of degree at most three that is irreducible must have a linear factor. Checking by hand the values $0,1,2,\ldots,11$ you can see it is not the case. What for is there to do?

Comment: You mean that a polynomial of degree at most three that is irreducible *cannot* have a linear factor? If it has a linear factor, it can be reduced.

The question not only asks to show that the polynomial is irreducible, but it also asks to show it is primitive.

Comment: Yes, sure. Ah, I missed that. What do you mean by primitive? The coefficients are in a field, so I don't think you mean the GCD of it's coefficients is 1.

Comment: Ok let $F=\{ax+b|a,b \in \mathbb Z_{11} \}/\{0\}$. Each element in this field is an equivalence class for polynomials modulo $k(x)$. The definition of primitive in my book is that $x$ generates this field. So if $k(x)$ is primitive, I can generate $F$ with powers of $x$ modulo $k(x)$.

Comment: This might help too:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: In the case of finite fields *primitive* has a different meaning (asking about the gcd of coefficients is kinda meaningless when the said coefficients are in a *field*). This is a common misunderstanding here. To remedy this I added an explanation into [finite-fields tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/finite-fields/info).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "The coefficients are in a field, so I don't think you mean the GCD of it's coefficients is 1." Aha. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quadratic polynomial $k(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ is primitive, iff the (multiplicative) order of the coset
$$
\alpha=x+\langle k(x)\rangle
$$
in the field $\Bbb{Z}_{11}[x]/\langle k(x)\rangle=\Bbb{F}_{121}$ is $120$. By Lagrange's theorem the order is always a factor of $120$. Thus it is one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20,24,30,40,60,120\}$. To speed up checking you can furthermore make the  observation that if $\alpha^{120/p}\neq1$ for all prime factors $p$ of $120$ (s0 $p=2,3$ or $5$), then the order has to be maximal, i.e. $\alpha$ is a primitive element (or $k(x)$ is a primitive polynomial). Of course, it may turn out that $\alpha$ is not primitive, in which case you will see evidence of this at some point.

In this task [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is your friend. Do remember to use the equation
$$
k(\alpha)=0\Longleftrightarrow\alpha^2=-(2\alpha+2)=9\alpha+9
$$
in each step.
For example
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\alpha^2&=&=-(2\alpha+2)\\
\alpha^4&=(\alpha^2)^2=(2\alpha+2)^2=4\alpha^2+8\alpha+4&=7
\end{array}
$$
I stop here, because we see that something slightly unexpected happened: $\alpha^4$ belongs to the prime field $\Bbb{Z}_{11}$. At this point I reveal that you can answer the question about primitivity simply by calculating the order of $7$ in the prime field. Leaving that to you!

With 20/20 hindsight we can see that the result about $\alpha^4$ is a consequence of the factorization (in $\Bbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ or actually already in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$)
$$
x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)
$$
showing that $k(x)$ is a factor of $x^4+4=x^4-7$.

Comment: The first paragraph here applies to the general task of proving that something is primitive. In this particular case something happened, so this is not fully needed :-)

Comment: Beautiful answer! +1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. By the second method that you discovered, how do you know you're not "skipping" any powers of $\alpha$ that may be equal to $1$? For example: $\alpha ^4 = 7 \implies \alpha ^{40}=1$. But could it be that for some $4 < i < 40$ ($i$ is not a multiple of $4$), $ \alpha ^i = 1$?

Comment: @Bobby: A good question. Here the main interest was whether $\alpha$ might be of order $120$, and this observation sufficed to eliminate that possibility. But it does also follow that the order has to be a multiple of $4$. Consider the set of exponents $m$ such that $\alpha^m\in\Bbb{Z}_{11}$. This set $H\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$ is closed under negation and addition, so it is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$. A non-trivial subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ is generated by their smallest positive element. Here $4$ is the smallest positive integer in $H$. Thus $H=4\Bbb{Z}$. But also the order of $\alpha\in H$.

Comment: Can you explain please why a non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is generated by its smallest positive element?

Comment: @Bobby: That's a basic fact about cyclic groups. A subgroup of a cyclic group is itself cyclic, and generated by the lowest power of the generator of the "mother group" in it. All this comes from the integer division algorithm step: $a=qb+r$ where $0\le r<|b|$.